# Change SelectionHighlight foreground of a TextBlock

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-10, uwp

First of all, my case is in UWP apps.

`TextBlock` has a property named `SelectionHighlightColor` that allows you specify the concrete color of the `Selection Area` when you select a text. Just like this:

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="This is a sample text" IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFFE751" Foreground="Black" />
```

That displays as:

[image]

In case you haven't notice, the foreground of selected text is always `White` even the background of selection area is of light color.

So is there any way to change the foreground of Selected text of `TextBlock` control?

Comment: Cant see how to do this as `TextBlock` doesnt have a Template and is a sealed class so cant be extended. It has a `SelectedText` property and `SelectioChanged` event but cant see any brushes to change

Comment: The TextBox class in Silverlight had a SelectionForeground property for this.. but the UWP TextBlock class does not seem to have...

Comment: Furthermore neither the RichTextBlock  nor the RichEditBox have a property for what you want achieve.. imho with TextBlock there is no way to do that...

Comment: Yes, most possibly there is no way to do this with TextBlock. Maybe I need to code the custom control that implement this effect, but this is totally not worth it.

Comment: I guess with the new Composition APIs in version 1511 you could do the following (just a wild guess):
- set highlight color to the inverted value of what you want
- get textblock visual
- enumerate children to find the hightlight box (I guess there should be one)
- invert the box's colors w/ an effect